# How can I create a table with names of directories and subdirectories in R?

Tags: r, knitr, r-markdown

**Problem**:

*I would like to produce a table of directory names and subdirectory names for a given path with R.*

**Desired Output**:

The output should be a data.frame or alike with two columns, that I can process with `knitr::kable` to produce a nice looking `.html` with `rmarkdown`.

Hence the result should look more or less like this:

```
|dir names            |subdir names         |
|:--------------------|:--------------------|
|                     |                     |
| DIR_1               | SUBDIR_1            |
|                     | SUBDIR_2            |
|                     | SUBDIR_3            |
| DIR_2               | SUBDIR_1            |
|                     | SUBDIR_2            |
```

**Minimal Example:**

This how far I got so far:

```
# Create directories
dir.create("DIR_1")
dir.create("DIR_2")
# Create subdirectories
dir.create("./DIR_1/SUBDIR_1")
dir.create("./DIR_1/SUBDIR_2")
dir.create("./DIR_1/SUBDIR_3")
dir.create("./DIR_2/SUBDIR_1")
dir.create("./DIR_2/SUBDIR_2")

library("knitr")
kable(list.dirs(path=".",
                recursive = TRUE, 
                full.names = FALSE),
      col.names = c("dirs & subdirs mixed"))


|dirs & subdirs mixed |
|:--------------------|
|                     |
|DIR_1                |
|DIR_1/SUBDIR_1       |
|DIR_1/SUBDIR_2       |
|DIR_1/SUBDIR_3       |
|DIR_2                |
|DIR_2/SUBDIR_1       |
|DIR_2/SUBDIR_2       |
```

**Additional question**:

*How could I add a third column that includes all file names stored in each subdirectory?*

Comment: Are you only interested in two levels (dir and subdir) or in an arbitraryly deep nesting with "subsubdirs" in the "subdirs"?

Comment: well, a solution that can handle deep nesting (>2 levels) would be nice.

Comment: Use `list.files` with the argument `include.dirs=TRUE` instead of `list.dirs`. Then you can split the directory with something like `stringr::str_split_fixed(FL,"/",n)` where `FL` is the file list and `n` is the maximum number of nesting directories.

Comment: To get the file name just use `basename(data frame)` and to get the directory name use `dirname()`

Comment: @nicola Will you post an answer based on your suggestion?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Based on [@nicola's suggestion to use `list.files` and `str_split_fixed`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35360189/how-can-i-create-a-table-with-names-of-directories-and-subdirectories-in-r#comment58427188_35360189), the following code generates a table of all directories and files in a given directory:

````
```{r setup, echo = FALSE, results = 'hide', warning = FALSE}
library(stringr)
lapply(X = c("demo", "demo/DIR_1", "demo/DIR_2", "demo/DIR_1/SUBDIR_1", "demo/DIR_1/SUBDIR_2", "demo/DIR_1/SUBDIR_3", "demo/DIR_2/SUBDIR_1", "demo/DIR_2/SUBDIR_2"),
       FUN = dir.create)
file.create("demo/DIR_2/SUBDIR_2/file1.txt")
file.create("demo/DIR_2/SUBDIR_2/file12.txt")
```

```{r}
paths <- list.files(path = "demo/", include.dirs = TRUE, recursive = TRUE)
mytable <- str_split_fixed(paths, pattern = "/", n = str_count(paths, "/") + 1)

colnames(mytable) <- paste("Level", seq(ncol(mytable)))

knitr::kable(mytable)
```
````

The first chunk just creates some demo directories and files. The actual work is done by `list.files` and `str_split_fixed`.

- `list.files` returns a vector with all directories, subdirectories and files therein, due to `include.dirs = TRUE` and `recursive = TRUE`.
- `str_split_fixed` splits the `paths` at `/` and returns a matrix. By `str_count(paths, "/") + 1` the number of split points is determined dynamically.

### Output:

```
|Level 1 |Level 2  |Level 3    |
|:-------|:--------|:----------|
|DIR_1   |         |           |
|DIR_1   |SUBDIR_1 |           |
|DIR_1   |SUBDIR_2 |           |
|DIR_1   |SUBDIR_3 |           |
|DIR_2   |         |           |
|DIR_2   |SUBDIR_1 |           |
|DIR_2   |SUBDIR_2 |           |
|DIR_2   |SUBDIR_2 |file1.txt  |
|DIR_2   |SUBDIR_2 |file12.txt |
```